# How to count how many cells have background color in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, gantt-chart

Is there a non VBA way to count how many cells have background color?

In this particular case I'm looking to automate a gantt diagram:

[image]

The goal is to fill a cell with any background the user likes, and then count the total of cells filled so we can calculate a duration.

I found some answers that say you can not count colors. However I'm not interested in how many of a particular color. Just want to count if is has color at all.

Comment: Why don't you let the user put x in the according cells - use conditional formatting for the color - and then count all cells with an x?

Comment: If the cells are filled by conditional formatting, then you should use the logic of the conditional formatting rule to count.

Answer (score 1):

Without VBA, you cannot create formulas that recognize cosmetic elements of a cell such as:

- Background Color
- Font
- Bold
- Size

As mentioned, you could have a cell's font be conditionally formatted based on something else (i.e. a cell not being empty) which a formula could also reference, but not the cosmetic setting itself.

While this is exactly what the question asked to avoid, for anyone looking how this  ***COULD*** be accomplished with VBA, see below custom formula. The second parameter is if a range of more than one cell then if the condition must apply to all (`and`) vs. a single being bold (`or`)

```
Function testIfBold(theRange As Range, Optional checkALL As Boolean) As Boolean
Dim aCell As Range

    For Each aCell In theRange.Cells
        If aCell.Font.Bold Then
            testIfBold = True
            If Not checkALL Then Exit Function
        Else
            testIfBold = False
            If checkALL Then Exit Function
        End If
    Next aCell
    
End Function
```